# Java Properties File Point to Another Properties File

Tags: java

I have a situation where I need to have a properties file point to the location of another properties file.  The first properties will contain one entry (server address) where the real properties file will be located on the network with all the relevant information.

Properties file 1 (config1.properties)

```
location=\\\\myserver\\path_of_real_propfile\\config2.properties
```

Properties file 2 (config2.properties)

```
URL=https://www.google.com/
```

So basically I would like if the user presses the Jbutton to go to google.com, the action listener reads Properties file 1 for the location of the properties file 2 and reads the URL and takes to user to google.com

```
JButton btngoog = new JButton("goog");
    btngoog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{

                FileReader reader = new FileReader("config2.properties");
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(reader);
                String googURL = properties.getProperty("URL");

                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(googURL));

                }
            catch(Exception ex){

                //do something
                }   
        }
    });
```

With the code above I have it working with a local properties file, but need help with using two.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue your having?

Comment: The issue is I can't get config1.properties to point to config2.properties to get the URL of google.com.  How do I add a config1.properties to the working code I posted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to get your location property from config1 (I assume it was already loaded) and pass that into the file reader

```
    try{
        String config2Location = config1Properties.getProperty("location");

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(config2Location);
        Properties config2Properties = new Properties();
        config2Properties.load(reader);
        String googURL = config2Properties.getProperty("URL");

        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(googURL));

        }
    catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mike that did it.